# problems connecting with the server of my website

Tags: web-services, webserver, server, hosting, web-hosting

I have a website and until some time ago it was administrated by a friend of mine; recently our relationships have been reduced, so I took the entire control of the website.

I'm not really expert with some aspects in the management of a web site. Actually I would make some back-end edits and I should connect with the server of the website.

I have the host IP, a username and a password. I tried to connect using Filezilla but I receive an error message: 530 Login incorrect.
So, I contacted the domain provider, I was convinced that the domain provider was the same of the hosting provider, but they  told me that it was not true and that the hosting for the website is provided by "someone else" (it could be an other hosting provider or a private web-server, for example).

I don't know what to do.
How can I connect to the server of my website? What am I missing?

p.s.: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be pointing filezilla at port 80. Try pointing at the ftp port (21 probably.) If this doesn't work it could be that the hosting uses a non standard port.

If in doubt get some support from the hosting company. Only they know how they are set up. If the use something like cpanel you can access files through that. They may be reluctant to help if you can't prove the site is yours. Usually by using the email address you set up when you bought the hosting.

And no, the domain provider does not have to be the same as the hosting provider. My domains are hosted at godaddy and I have odd bits of hosting all over the place ;)

Comment: I tried with port 80 and it doesn' work.

I don't know who is the hosting company, I know the domain provider because I see it from the whois while about the nameservers I just have this:
ns1.d00ic6-vm.sphostserver.com
ns2.d00ic6-vm.sphostserver.com

.Then, if i write the IP in the browser I see this http://imgur.com/4gOYrdN Does it have something to do with cPanel?

Comment: The host seems to be http://www.serverplan.com. from this whois search https://who.is/whois/https://sphostserver.com. You need to talk to them. They are going to ask some hard questions about why they should give you access if you are not the owner of the hosting.

Comment: yea, I can imagine. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Pleasure. Sorry I can't get you any further down the road to a solution.

Comment: well, I just contacted serverplan.com, they told me to talk with the previous administrator, obviously :\